# iPhone App: implementation of Drag and drop images in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, drag-and-drop

In my iPhone App I want to implemented functionality as shown  below

[image]

user can pick a shape(an image) from one view and put in other view

How can I achieve this?

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678735/adding-drag-and-drop-component-to-ios-app/31963306#31963306](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678735/adding-drag-and-drop-component-to-ios-app/31963306#31963306) You can try this link enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below link [drag and drop image around the screen](http://web.archive.org/web/20081022074350/www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/)

also [try this](https://github.com/Hegaka/HGKDragAndDropRecycleBin)

Comment: hi, your first link is dead. for future references, can you post the contents of the link in your comment. SO is meant to be a one stop shop and shouldn't link to potentially dead links

Comment: Link 1 cached: https://web.archive.org/web/20081022074350/www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer. That will give you messages when the view is moved and when it is dropped. When it is moved, update its center. When it is dropped, check if its position is within the bounds of the view you want to drop in. (You might need to convert coordinates to the target view's coordinate system.) If it is, do the appropriate action.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the previous post which will definitely help you to achieve this functionality...

1. [Basic Drag and Drop in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707858/basic-drag-and-drop-in-ios)
2. [Building drag and drop interface on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955629/building-drag-and-drop-interface-on-iphone)
3. [iPhone drag/drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979555/iphone-drag-drop)

For all of above link, You have to keep in mind that You need to first get `TouchesBegin` event for any Control and then you have to get the `TouchesMoved` event for same control.

In `TouchesMoved` event, you just have to get the center point (CGPoint) of the Control. And when you release the control will be set at that `CGPoint`. If this creates problem then you can take that `CGPoint` in variable and set that Point in `TouchesEnded` event.

For your case, i think you must have to maintain the **Hierarchy** of the Views...Else while dragging you view may not be visible...

**FOR MORE CODING PART :**

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        NSLog(@"%f,%f", self.center.x, self.center.y);
        CGPoint newLoc = CGPointZero;

        newLoc = [self.mainView convertPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview] toView:self.superview];
        float newX = newLoc.x + self.superview.frame.origin.x + (self.frame.size.width /2) + [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self].x ;
        float newY = newLoc.y - (((UIScrollView *)self.superview).contentOffset.y *2) ;
        NSLog(@"content offset %f", ((UIScrollView *)self.superview).contentOffset.y);

        self.scrollParent.scrollEnabled = NO;
        NSLog(@"%f,%f", self.center.x, self.center.y);

        newLoc = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
        [self.superview touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];                                                               
        [self removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"%f,%f", self.center.x, self.center.y);


        self.center = CGPointMake(newLoc.x, newLoc.y);
        [self.mainView addSubview:self];
        NSLog(@"%f,%f", self.center.x, self.center.y);

        [self.mainView bringSubviewToFront:self];
        isInScrollview = NO;
}   

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"stalk" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.001];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    self.center = [touch locationInView: self.superview];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
    if ((self.center.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2)) > 150 && hasExitedDrawer && !self.scrollParent.dragging ) {
        self.scrollParent.scrollEnabled = NO;

        [self.delegate moveItemsDownFromIndex: ((self.center.y + (self.scrollParent.contentOffset.y)) / 44) + 1 ];
        //NSLog(@"%i", ((self.center.y + (self.scrollParent.contentOffset.y *2)) / 44) + 1);
    }

    if (self.center.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2) < 150) {

        hasExitedDrawer = YES;

    }

}   

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ((self.center.x + (self.frame.size.width / 2)) > 150 && hasExitedDrawer && !self.scrollParent.dragging ) {
        CGPoint newLoc = CGPointZero;

        newLoc = [self.scrollParent convertPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview] toView:self.superview];
        float newY = newLoc.y + (self.scrollParent.contentOffset.y *2);

        [self.scrollParent insertSubview:self atIndex:((self.center.y + (self.scrollParent.contentOffset.y)) / 44) ];
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0, newY, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
        isInScrollview = YES;
        hasExitedDrawer = NO;
    }
}
```

This code may cantains some irrelevant but gives you more idea...

Answer (score 2):

You can use below open source libraries:

1. [Library 1 OBDragDrop](https://github.com/Oblong/OBDragDrop)
2. [Library 2 AJWDraggableDroppable](https://github.com/adamwaite/AJWDraggableDroppable)
3. [Library 3 iOS-DragAndDrop](https://github.com/brynbellomy/iOS-DragAndDrop)
4. [Library 4 ios-drag-and-drop](https://github.com/frenetisch-applaudierend/ios-drag-and-drop)

Answer (score 1):

[Adding drag and drop component to iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678735/adding-drag-and-drop-component-to-ios-app/31963306#31963306From) the Question

i thing you are going to Build a feature like Add to cart in Most of the Shopping Apps like Amazon, Flip kart and etc..

Answer (score -2):

Three step solution

1) u'll have to implement/listen for touch events

2) implement dragging and touch events

3) and then manage movetosuperview method.

Comment: Source code for how to drag and drop with snap to area http://stackoverflow.com/a/9233102/1537178