# UINavigationBar registering touches for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, touch, uinavigationbar

I have created an app wherein I have a large scroll view (two page heights), and the navigation bar is visible.  Further, I have it setup so that the scroll view starts off scrolled to the bottom page, and touches below the 30px mark are not registered by the UIScroll view (e.g. if you touch further than 30px below the nav bar, you will be able to press buttons but NOT scroll the UIScrollView).  This all works excellently and allows me to make it seem like you are pulling down a window from above, all and all a neat effect.

The problem is that in use case testing, many users seem to be tapping too high (hitting the UINavigationBar) and thus their swipe gestures to try to pull down the window aren't being read.  Basically, if the touch starts on the nav bar, the entire gesture is ignored.  This leads to users getting either frustrated (knowing that they should be able to pull down the window but being unable to) or thinking that the pull down has been disabled for some reason.

I'd like to implement a way such that if the user's touch starts from within the UINavigationBar but isn't on one of the navigation buttons, the touch is passed down to the UIScrollView.  Is this possible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: I used something similar to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10365223/1669034) to get the effect I mentioned above with the scroll view only scrolling if you start at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using custom navigation bar. Inherit from UINavigation bar and then add a sub view where you want and add a gesture there.

Comment: I can add a subview to the default UINavigationBar which has a gesture recognizer on it, but I'd rather pass the touches straight through to the scrollview rather than having a separate gesture recognizer if possible.

Comment: @Doc but i am not sure whether it will give gesture on the edge of the nav bar and top of your view together.

Comment: I ended up resorting to this to do the trick.  Honestly not exactly what I wanted, but at least it solved the primary issue.