# drag and drop images if placed on certain area call function

Tags: ios, image, drag

I think the title is pretty self explaining. I need an icon that is dragged by users touch. If this icon is droped on a certain area I would like to call a function. How´s that possible?

Thanks a lot,

Tyler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add UIPanGesture to the View.

> ```
> - (void)viewDidLoad
> {
>
>     [super viewDidLoad];
>     UIPanGestureRecognizer *pangesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageIsMoved:)];
>     pangesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
>
>     [self.myView addGestureRecognizer:pangesture];
>
> }
> ```

- Write a gesture method when drag is over

> ```
> -(void)imageIsMoved:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
>
>     CGRect frameToBeCompared;
>     if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
>
>         UIView *v = [gesture view];
>         CGRect viewFrame  = v.frame;
>         if (CGRectEqualToRect(frameToBeCompared, viewFrame)) {
>             [self callMyMethod];
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658114/iphone-app-implementation-of-drag-and-drop-images-in-uiview) Once you have the basics down, you can use an if statement to check the bounds of your icon and if they hit a specific spot call your next function.

[Here's another example from one of my favorite iOS tutorial sites, www.raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites)